# jQuery datapicker select-able date after user input start date and end date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

First I use date range to get user input for 
start date and end date.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

How to set next input date only allow between user selected start date and end date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vAT4R/

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="date1_start" />
<input type="text" id="date1_stop" />

<hr />

<input type="text" id="date2_start" />
<input type="text" id="date2_stop" />
```

#### JS

```
var dates2 = $( "#date2_start, #date2_stop" ).datepicker();

var dates = $( "#date1_start, #date1_stop" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var option = this.id == "date1_start" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings );
        dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        dates2.datepicker( "option", option, date );
    }
});
```

Comment: many thanks Ayman. :)
would like to ask u. I tried to use datepicker with time for next input from
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/
But it make datepicker wont work anymore.
only can use datetimepicker.